# Solve combinatorics problem to target desired result

Tags: algebra-precalculus, linear-programming

I wonder if someone would be able to suggest some solution, programming technique or, at least, the right name for the problem, so I could research more.

- I have a problem where I given a number of jugs with solution of water and spirit.
- I need to find a combination of jugs, which will give me requested volume and requested % of spirit in the solution, when liquids from selected jugs are poured into a single empty jug.
- I don't have to use whole jug of solution, and can use only some percentage of the solution.

***For example I have jugs:***

Jug 1: **10,000 ml** of solution contains **2.3%** of spirit

Jug 2:  **8,000 ml** of solution contains **3.5%** of spirit

Jug 3: **12,000 ml** of solution contains **1.7%** of spirit

Jug N: etc.

***Target***

Find volume of liquid I need to take from them to get **7,000 ml** containing **2.5%** of spirit. The goal is to ***use as little jugs from the given set as possible***, which would produce desired combination of volume and % of spirit.

---

I have come up with the formula, but have no idea how to solve it without brute force iteration.
$$
y_r=\frac{((x_1*V_1)*R_1)+((x_2*V_2)*R_2)+((x_n*V_n)*R_n)}{(x_1*V_1)+(x_2*V_2)+(x_n*V_n)}
$$
$$
V_r=(x_1*V_1)+(x_2*V_2)+(x_n*V_n)
$$
where:

yr - required % of spirit in the final solution (this is formula of weighted average)

Vr - required volume of the final solution

x - the percentage of liquid I need to take from a jug number 1, 2, etc.

V - volume of liquid in jug 1, 2, etc.

R - % of spirit in jug 1, 2, etc.

---

I would really appreciate if someone can comment or suggest the way to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Each mixture can be described as a vector of $N$ real numbers from interval $[0,1]$; $i$-ith number corresponding to the fraction of the volume of $i$-th jug we use. The mixing has very nice property: if we can produce mixture $A$ and mixture $B$ (represented as vectors), we can also produce any convex combination of these: $pA + (1-p)B$, with $p\in [0,1]$.

Now, let's try to make two special mixtures: $W$ and $S$. Both will have the same total volume as the target mixture we're trying to make, but they'll differ in the composition. $W$ will be as weak as possible (the less spirit, the better), while $S$ will be as strong as we can get it. Clearly, if our desired mixture has less spirit than $W$, or more spirit than $S$, it cannot be made.

If it lies between those two, the convexity property tells us how to produce it: since $S$ and $W$ have the right total volume already, we only need to mix them so that the spirit concentration will come out right. If $c_S, c_W$ and $c_R$ denote the spirit concentration in $S$, $W$ and the desired mixture $R$ respectively, we have $$R = \left(\frac{c_R-c_W}{c_S-c_W}\right)S + \left(\frac{c_S-c_R}{c_S-c_W}\right)W  $$

Making $S$ (and likewise $W$) is not too difficult either. In order to get as much spirit as possible, we start with the jar with the highest concentration of spirit and keep pouring it in until we either finish the jar completely, or we reach the desired total volume of liquid. This is so-called [greedy approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) approach and it's not too difficult to see that it indeed produces the optimal result in this case: If that wasn't the case, some of the liquid we poured from higher-concentration jar would have to be replaced (in the optimal mixture) by liquid from a lower-concentration one... but that would make the total amount of spirit lower; a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Pieter. This formula and approach definitely works. Is it possible to expand this formula and use it for 3,  and possibly more jugs? Not only for (W)eek and (S)trong?

Comment: Note that the $W$eak and $S$trong jugs are created by mixing the liquids from the actual jugs you start with (which there can be any number of); they are just temporary holders used in the process.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can even introduce a cost per ml of each jug and find a solution which minimizes the cost, by linear programming.  The decision variables are the volume to take from each jug.  Your constraints are (1) the volume you take from each jug is limited by the volume of liquid in the jug; (2) the total volume of liquid must equal your goal for total volume; (3) the total quantity of spirits must equal your goal for spirits.  Oh yes, and don't forget non-negativity.  All these are linear constraints, and the total cost is a linear function.  So the problem fits the requirements for a linear program.

Comment: Thanks. I've already tried to solve this with Microsoft Solver Foundation. The solver finds the target volume and %. However, it tends to use all jugs ignoring the goal implied on minimizing the number of jugs being used. So, for example, if I have 6 jugs it will deep in all 6 of them.

Comment: @Alex: You might want to specify the "minimize the number of jugs" expectation explicitly in the question statement -- it does change the problem quite a bit (the condition on *number* of jugs is no longer linear).